# Connecting to a DBF in Visual Basic

Tags: vbscript, dbf, dbase

We have a Windows application that stores data in DBF. I need to connect to a certain table `a_sname.dbf` and extract the `SN_ACCOUNT`, `SN_CURRBAL` and `SN_CRLIM` columns to a text file to be imported by another application.

The text file ideally needs to look like.

```
SN_ACCOUNT     SN_CURRBAL     SN_CRLIM
10             100            1000
20             200            2000
```

The above is an example only.

At the moment I am looking to at least get connected to the DBF.

I have BASH scripting with Oracle SQL knowledge but the Windows side is all new to me. I have the drive mapped to `Z:\`.

---

**Update 1:** Here is the script that I'm testing.

```
Option Explicit

Dim sDir : sDir = "Z:\"
Dim sCS  : sCS  = Join(Array( _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
      , "Data Source=" & sDir _
      , "Extended Properties=""dBASE IV;""" _
), ";")
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oCN.Open sCS
Dim oRS : Set oRS = oCN.Execute("SELECT SN_ACCOUNT,SN_CURRBAL,SN_CRLIM FROM a_sname.dbf")
Do Until oRS.EOF
   WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).Name, oRS.Fields(0).Value
   oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oCN.Close
```

I am getting the error message `Microsoft JET Database Engine: External table is not in the expected format.`.

---

**Update 2:** Here is a screenshot of the table information of `a_sname.dbf`.

[image]

---

**Update 3:** It works! Here is the query that I am using.

`SELECT SN_ACCOUNT,SN_CURRBAL,SN_CRLIM FROM a_sname.dbf`

Here is the echo that I am using.

`WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).Value, oRS.Fields(1).Value, oRS.Fields(2).Value`.

Is it possible to pipe all this to a text file and have the columns spaced more evenly?

[image]

Comment: For completeness, you should publish the connection string too. Formatting the output for the recordset deserves a question of its own (it does not depend on the datasource).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **the** [source](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/) your connection string for the ADODB.CONNECTION should look something like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\FileServer01\Server VFTP Dynamic\Data;
Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;
```

Your first (test) query could be

```
SELECT * FROM [a_sname.dbf]
```

In case of trouble, I'd

1. map `\\FileServer01\Server VFTP Dynamic` to a drive letter, change the connection string accordingly and try again
2. use Data Sources to establish a connection interactively/with help of a GUI and use this experience to build the connection string

**Added:**

Some tested code to increase your confidence:

```
Option Explicit

Dim sDir : sDir = "\\gent\eh\...etc...\testdata\dbf"
Dim sCS  : sCS  = Join(Array( _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
      , "Data Source=" & sDir _
      , "Extended Properties=""dBASE IV;""" _
), ";")
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oCN.Open sCS
Dim oRS : Set oRS = oCN.Execute("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM [tblAbles]")
Do Until oRS.EOF
   WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).Name, oRS.Fields(0).Value
   oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oCN.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 22934726.vbs
RTATID 2
RTATID 3
```

**Troubleshooting I:**

1. In the code you published, `sDir` contains a file spec ("Z:\a_sname.dbf"), not a folder/directory spec
2. Windows ??, ?? Bit (do you need to work in a 32 Bit environment?)
3. ADO Version? `WScript.Echo CreateObject("ADODB.Connection").Version`

**Troubleshooting II:**

1. Make sure a_sname.dbf is a valid .dbf (of version ?) by opening it using some other tool (Excel, Access, ODBC, ...)
2. Tweak the "dBase IV" property

**Troubleshooting III:**

1. see [here](http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm) for getting the version from the file header
2. use a GUI (e.g. Data Sources) to find possible values for "dBase XX"

**Troubleshooting (not dBase!) IV:**

1. According to **the** source, you can/must(?) use a VFP specific connection string: maybe
   [`Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\MyDataDirectory\;Collating Sequence=general;`](https://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/)
2. Perhaps you need to [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) a provider DLL (be carefull wrt versions!)

Comment: Thanks. That is a great help. I've come up with this script with is basically yours but with my parameters: http://pastebin.com/rUR5X6QU. I'm getting the error message `ADODB.Connection: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.` but what actually needs to be installed here?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with the current script. I have fixed `sDir`. I am using Windows 8 64-bit (but opening a 32-bit `cmd.exe` to run it) and `6.2` is shown when I run that command.

Comment: Thanks. I have uploaded a screenshot of the table information opened in DBF Plus. I did also open it in Microsoft Excel but didn't see version numbers shown anywhere. If you can point me in the right direction then I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks. It is Visual FoxPro.

Comment: Thanks. I now have a working script thanks to you! I updated the question.